# Why does CGAffineTransformMakeScale start from the original position and not from the current one?

Tags: xcode5

This issue has been bugging me for some days now and I can't seem to find any solution to it whatsoever. My project is simply about a circle that has some texts on it so when I press on a button it grows big enough so that the texts can be easily read. However, the texts are distributed in a circular way around the circle so I first need to rotate the circle and then when one of the texts is right in front of me, I press the button to resize the circle but instead of starting to grow from the last position after the rotation, it gets reset to its initial position. How can I  tackle this issue? 
Thank you.

Here is the code that causes this issue:

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.5];

```
circle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(5,5);


[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:NO];

[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];

circle.alpha = 1.0;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's to do with the different tree's represented within a Core Animation object.  From [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CoreAnimationBasics/CoreAnimationBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH2-SW19):

> An app using Core Animation has three sets of layer objects. Each set
>   of layer objects has a different role in making the content of your
>   app appear onscreen:
>
> - Objects in the model layer tree (or simply “layer tree”) are the ones your app interacts with the most. The objects in this tree are
>     the model objects that store the target values for any animations.
>     Whenever you change the property of a layer, you use one of these
>     objects.
> - Objects in the presentation tree contain the in-flight values for any running animations. Whereas the layer tree objects contain the
>     target values for an animation, the objects in the presentation tree
>     reflect the current values as they appear onscreen. You should never
>     modify the objects in this tree. Instead, you use these objects to
>     read current animation values, perhaps to create a new animation
>     starting at those values.
> - Objects in the render tree perform the actual animations and are private to Core Animation.

What this means for you, is that once an animation has completed, you need to ensure the changes in the presentation layer (which are the subject of the animation) are reflected in the model layer.  This can normally be achieved by disabling animation and setting the final property values.

Comment: Thanks a lot trojanfoe for you fast reply. I really appreciate it.      I'm still new to this whole objective-c thing so if you please show me how I can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer and now I know why the image position keeps getting reset every time. It's because of CGAffineTransformMakeScale which overrides the current position with the original one so I used CGAffineTransformScale instead and that fixed the problem for me.

Here is the code that worked for me:

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{image.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(image.transform, 5, 5);}

```
                       completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                 }];
```

I hope this helps others as much as it has helped me!

Again, thank you trojanfoe for your answer which kind of helped me in my search for the right answer ;)